# Can this SQL Server stored procedure be converted to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am trying to convert a SQL Server stored procedure to Oracle. The original code of the stored procedure is of 1000 lines, and I try to grasp some key functionality in a sample code. The key is to declare some variables which is to do some counter and condition checks and to create some #temp tables which is to store some intermediate data for later processing.  I think I have to use these temp tables.

This is the SQL Server code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc]  
  @InputString VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
AS 

DECLARE @DONE INT = 0
DECLARE @I INT = 1; DECLARE @J INT = 1
DECLARE @OutputString VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @OutputString = ''

WHILE @I <= 40000
  BEGIN
    SET @OutputString = @OutputString + '1234567890'
    SET @I = @I + 1
  END
--

SET @I = 1

CREATE TABLE #temp1(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),COL1 VARCHAR(MAX),COL2 VARCHAR(MAX))
WHILE @I <= 10
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #temp1 values(@InputString + '-Col1-'+CAST(@I as VARCHAR(10)),'Col2-'+CAST(@I as VARCHAR(10)))
   SET @I = @I + 1
 END  
-- 

CREATE TABLE #temp2(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),COL3 VARCHAR(MAX),COL4 VARCHAR(MAX),COL5 VARCHAR(MAX))
WHILE @J <= 15
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO #temp2 values('Col3-'+CAST(@J as VARCHAR(10))
                            ,@OutputString + '-Col4-'+CAST(@J as VARCHAR(10))
                            , 'Col5-'+CAST(@J as VARCHAR(10)))
   SET @J = @J + 1
 END

SELECT distinct
    temp1.ID
   ,temp1.Col1
   ,temp1.COL2
   ,temp2.Col3
   ,temp2.Col4
   ,temp2.Col5
 FROM #temp1 temp1 
inner join  #temp2 temp2
on temp1.ID = temp2.ID
WHERE temp1.ID < 5
GO
```

To execute the stored procedure, I use

```
exec [dbo].[TestProc] 'testing'
```

Which works fine.

On the web, I find a SQL converter, and it can convert my code into Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TestProc ( 
  p_InputString VARCHAR DEFAULT ''), cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
AS 

v_DON_ NUMBER(10) := 0;
v_I NUMBER(10) := 1; v_J NUMBER(10) := 1;
v_Out_ VARCHAR(MAX);
BEGIN
  v_Out_ := '';
  WHILE v_I <= 40000
  LOOP
    v_Out_ := v_Out_ || '1234567890';
    v_I := v_I + 1;
  END LOOP;
--
  v_I := 1;
  CREATE TABLE #temp1(ID NUMBER(10) ,COL1 VARCHAR(MAX),COL2 VARCHAR(MAX));

 -- Generate ID using sequence and trigger
  CREATE SEQUENCE #temp1_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER #temp1_seq_tr
     BEFORE INSERT ON #temp1 FOR EACH ROW
       WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
     BEGIN
       SELECT #temp1_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
     END;
    /
  WHILE v_I <= 10
      LOOP
         INSERT INTO #temp1 values(p_InputString || '-Col1-'||TO_CHAR(v_I(10)),'Col2-'||TO_CHAR(v_I(10)))
         v_I := v_I + 1;
      END LOOP;  
-- 
  CREATE TABLE #temp2(ID NUMBER(10) ,COL3 VARCHAR(MAX),COL4 VARCHAR(MAX),COL5 VARCHAR(MAX));

   -- Generate ID using sequence and trigger
  CREATE SEQUENCE #temp2_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER #temp2_seq_tr
     BEFORE INSERT ON #temp2 FOR EACH ROW
       WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
     BEGIN
         SELECT #temp2_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
     END;
    /
  WHILE v_J <= 15
      LOOP
         INSERT INTO #temp2 values('Col3-'||TO_CHAR(v_J(10))
                            ,v_Out_ || '-Col4-'||TO_CHAR(v_J(10))
                            , 'Col5-'||TO_CHAR(v_J(10)))
         v_J := v_J + 1;
      END LOOP;

  OPEN cur FOR SELECT distinct
    temp1.ID
   ,temp1.Col1
   ,temp1.COL2
   ,temp2.Col3
   ,temp2.Col4
   ,temp2.Col5
  FROM #temp1 temp1 
   inner join  #temp2 temp2
    on temp1.ID = temp2.ID
   WHERE temp1.ID < 5;
GO
```

This Oracle code looks weird to me. It creates some temp tables in a way which seems not allowed in Oracle. Can someone try to run this Oracle code and see what happens?

Also I wish to get some sense about how to convert the SQL Server stored procedure into Oracle. Can you convert this code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: in oracle you can use global temporary tables or load data into an array/type/object.  It is not best practice in Oracle to create tables for intermediate work as is more common in SQL server

Comment: Yes, I agree with you Kevinsky.  But I don't know for my case how to create the global temp tables.  I mean where I should create them: before my stored proc or inside the SP?

Answer (score 1):

This compiles on Oracle 11.  It does not address the use of temp tables which could be done away with entirely if I understood what it was supposed to do.
Changes include:

- use VARCHAR2(4000) instead of VARCHAR(MAX)
- do not start object names with #, it makes your life easier
- When you start a procedure with Create or replace it must end with END
- move the creation of objects outside the procedure, run them once, use the procedure as many times as you like

---

```
  CREATE TABLE temp1(ID NUMBER(10) ,COL1 VARCHAR2(4000),COL2 VARCHAR2(4000));

 -- Generate ID using sequence and trigger
  CREATE SEQUENCE temp1_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER temp1_seq_tr
     BEFORE INSERT ON temp1 FOR EACH ROW
       WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
     BEGIN
       SELECT temp1_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
     END;
  CREATE TABLE temp2(ID NUMBER(10) ,COL3 VARCHAR2(4000),COL4 VARCHAR2(4000),COL5 VARCHAR2(4000));

   -- Generate ID using sequence and trigger
  CREATE SEQUENCE temp2_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER temp2_seq_tr
     BEFORE INSERT ON temp2 FOR EACH ROW
       WHEN (NEW.ID IS NULL)
     BEGIN
         SELECT temp2_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
     END;
    /
    ------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC(P_INPUTSTRING VARCHAR2 DEFAULT '',
                                     CUR           OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS

  V_DON_ NUMBER(10) := 0;
  V_I    NUMBER(10) := 1;
  V_J    NUMBER(10) := 1;
  V_OUT_ VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  V_OUT_ := '';
  WHILE V_I <= 40000 LOOP
    V_OUT_ := V_OUT_ || '1234567890';
    V_I    := V_I + 1;
  END LOOP;
  --
  V_I := 1;

  WHILE V_I <= 10 LOOP
    INSERT INTO #TEMP1
    VALUES
      (P_INPUTSTRING || '-Col1-' || TO_CHAR(V_I(10)),
       'Col2-' || TO_CHAR(V_I(10))) V_I := V_I + 1;
  END LOOP;
  -- 

  WHILE V_J <= 15 LOOP
    INSERT INTO #TEMP2
    VALUES
      ('Col3-' || TO_CHAR(V_J(10)),
       V_OUT_ || '-Col4-' || TO_CHAR(V_J(10)),
       'Col5-' || TO_CHAR(V_J(10))) V_J := V_J + 1;
  END LOOP;

  OPEN CUR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT TEMP1.ID,
                    TEMP1.COL1,
                    TEMP1.COL2,
                    TEMP2.COL3,
                    TEMP2.COL4,
                    TEMP2.COL5
      FROM #TEMP1 TEMP1
     INNER JOIN #TEMP2 TEMP2
        ON TEMP1.ID = TEMP2.ID
     WHERE TEMP1.ID < 5;
END TESTPROC;
```

Comment: This is great Kevinsky! Can you please run the SP and check the result?

Comment: @user1816353 You are not going to have much success translating SQL Server to Oracle without somewhere to test. I suggest http://apex.oracle.com.

Comment: If SQL Server code is using `varchar(max)` there probably is an expectation that strings greater than 8000 characters will be stored. Oracle's `varchar2(4000)` is unlikely to be a good substitute. The equivalent is a `clob`. But the code for dealing with clobs is different, sometimes, than varchar2s. Also, you have a `varchar2(max)` declaration in the translated stored procedure.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance corrected thank you.. and I agree a CLOB is a better choice but as I mentioned this seems to be a dummy procedure as all it does is create two tables with repetitive number strings and join them.  Hard to imagine a business use case for this...